# Azure V1 function on CosmosDB change feed triggers all changes when published

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a function app that connects to the cosmosDB change feed, and it works well but I have an issue that when I publish the app, it processes changes for all documents currently in the monitored collection which seems wrong

The function is initialised as follows

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "XXX",
            collectionName: "YYY",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDb",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases", LeaseCollectionPrefix = "cloud")]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
        {
}
```

the only change I did was to change the LeaseCollectionPrefix, could that cause the trigger to receive changes for all documents in the collection because its seen as a new lease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CosmosDB trigger detects document changes

1. When it's running and changes happen
2. After it's triggered the first time in scenario 1(ContinuationToken in lease is updated from null to a valid value), it can receive all changes which happened later, even including those happened when it was not running.

In your situation, I assume you may have used the `cloud` lease before and have done some changes to the CosmosDB when the trigger with `cloud` lease is not running. This time you publish the code, all changes are displayed together.

Apparently, solution is to delete the old `cloud` lease in your `leases` collection.